# UIDocumentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem error in ios8- Unknown activity items supplied

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

`UIDocumentInteractionController` `presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem` gives me a console error in ios8 hardware (and not on 7.1 hardware or earlier):

```
 Unknown activity items supplied: (
    {
    "com.adobe.pdf" = ;
},
""
 )
```

In my official App Store version of my app, the app crashes at this point. When I compile and run on my iPad it just gives the error but does not crash.

My code:

**In the .h:**

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *docInteractionController;
```

**In the .m:**

```
self.docInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];

self.docInteractionController.delegate = self;
//UIBarButtonItem *element is an element in my toolbar
[self.docInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:element animated:YES];
```

If I do a `NSLog` of docInteractionController.UTI I see "com.adobe.pdf" at the console, so the UTI is being recognized properly.

I can get around the "Unknown activity items" by using presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem instead of presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem for the UIDocumentInteractionController call, but I want to show the user the print and email options as well, not only the external app opening options.

Tested on iPad version 8.0.2. Xcode version 6.0.1, deployment target 6.0 (also tested with deployment target 8.0). All objective-c. Running on iPad version 7.1 does not produce the error.

Comment: sounds like a wonderful iOS 8 bug

Comment: I have the exact same issue on IOS 8.0.2 iPad.

Answer (score 7):

See radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5800473659441152

- As noted you can use presentOpenInMenu instead of presentOptionsMenu. You will loose the mail option but you can do it yourself with MFMailComposeViewController with a dedicated mail button.
- Or use UIActivityViewController with an "Open In" activity item.
- Or just a UIActivityViewController without an "Open In" activity item if that is enough
- Or do presentOptionsMenu on iOS7 runtime and UIActivityViewController on iOS8+ runtime (where share extensions exist)

Comment: Thanks for the radar link! That's pretty much exactly what my bug is.

Answer (score 4):

For people not wanting to use `UIActivityViewController` because the document controller is what we want (all actions show up): you can get around the crash by retaining the `UIDocumentInteractionController`, e.g. by assigning it to a property and releasing when the document interaction finishes:

```
- (void)share:(id)sender
{
    self.documentInteraction = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:_shareURL];
    _documentInteraction.delegate = self;
    _documentInteraction.name = self.title;

    [_documentInteraction presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:_actionItem animated:YES];
}

- (void)documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOptionsMenu:(UIDocumentInteractionController *)controller
{
    if (controller == _documentInteraction) {
        self.documentInteraction = nil;
    }
}
```

The log will still show up, at least in debug, haven't checked with a release build. But it all works.

Comment: When you say "the log will show up", do you mean you still get the console error/warning? Because when I compile and run currently, it doesn't crash, it just gives an error and keeps going.

Comment: Yes, I mean the "Unknown activity items supplied" is still logged to the console.

Comment: It works, but it's so slow that the app becomes quite unusable. Maybe it depends on the size of the PDF? In my case, it takes a few seconds until the popover is shown.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the problem for me:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^() {
      [_docController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:button.bounds inView:button animated:YES];              
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion! Sadly, this did not change behavior for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same console logs, but only in debug builds. Try creating a release build and you should see it still prints the "Unknown activity items supplied" error, but without the entire contents of the file.

Comment: I get the entire content of the file even with release build.